# VSCode & Git problem : Can't undo because HEAD doesn't point to any commit

Tags: git, visual-studio-code

I have a problem with VSCode, when I want to undo last commit, pop-up message is "Can't undo because HEAD doesn't point to any commit."

But I have already commit and manually in shell it's work.

Last logs in "output" window :

```
> git status -z -u
> git symbolic-ref --short HEAD
> git for-each-ref --format=%(refname)%00%(upstream:short)%00%(upstream:track)%00%(objectname) refs/heads/master refs/remotes/master
fatal: unknown upstream: format track
```

git status :

```
[DEV - -@- -]$ git status
# On branch master
# Your branch is ahead of 'origin/master' by 1 commit.
#   (use "git push" to publish your local commits)
#
# Changes not staged for commit:
#   (use "git add <file>..." to update what will be committed)
#   (use "git checkout -- <file>..." to discard changes in working directory)
#
#       modified:   ---
#       modified:   ---
#       modified:   ---
#       modified:   ---
#
no changes added to commit (use "git add" and/or "git commit -a")
```

Image VSCode : [As you can see, when I commit in VSCode, the synchronize button doesn't show changes](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Apr7d.png)

Can you help me to fix git?

Answer (score 0):

I answer to myself, I had git 1.x. I switched to git 2.x and all my problems disappeared, strange that VSCode doesn't warn that there are potentially bugs with git 1.x

Answer (score 0):

In my case the problem was related to remote/local branch name mismatch (caused by different capitalization). Commits could still be reverted using `git reset <commit-hash>`, then I pushed whatever I wanted pushed, removed the branch `git branch -d branchname` and checked it out again with the correct name `git checkout branchName`, and Undo Last Commit started working again.